# How to get the sum of the last index from multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know this is a very basic question, but I am not able to write the correct code for this. Let's say I have 3 arrays:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
arr3 = [7,3,2,1]
```

I want the sum of the last index, i.e. `4+ 8 + 1 = 13`

I am not able to write the correct for loop for the same.

**EDIT :**

My array is inside an object as shown below:
[image]

So, I will have more arrays inside the object. So how do I proceed with this?

Comment: Can you share your approach?

Comment: just iterate over the arrays and sum up `array[i][array[i].length-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let ree = {
    arr1: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    arr2: [5, 6, 7, 8],
    arr3: [7, 3, 2, 1]
};

let total = 0;
for (var key in ree) {
    if (Array.isArray(ree[key])) {
        total += ree[key][ree[key].length - 1];
    }
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using array.length property,

```
sum = arr1[arr1.length - 1] + arr2[arr2.length - 1] + arr3[arr3.length - 1];
```

If they are inside another array you can do something like this,

```js
   let parentArr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[7,3,2,1]];
   let sum = 0;
   for(let i =0;i<parentArr.length; i++) {
       sum = sum + parentArr[i][parentArr[i].length - 1];
   }
   console.log(sum);
```

If the arrays are inside an object you can do the following,

```js
let parentObj = {'arr1': [1,2,3,4], 'arr2': [5,6,7,8], 'arr3': [7,3,2,1]};
let sum = 0;
let keys = Object.keys(parentObj);
for(let i =0;i<keys.length; i++) {
     sum = sum + parentObj[keys[i]][parentObj[keys[i]].length - 1];
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. 1 issue I am facing is my arrays are inside an object. SO, I am getting an error on the for loop as `Property length does not exist on type {}` while writing `for(var i=0; i<dataSets.length; i++) {}`. How to solve this?

Comment: Updated for object as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this short and easy solution

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
let arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
let arr3 = [7,3,2,1]

arrList = [arr1,arr2,arr3]
finalSum = arrList.reduce((acc, cur) => acc+[...cur].pop(), 0)
```

i created a copy of arrays in reduce as pop modifies original array.

if your array is inside object as key value pair you can get it as array like this

```
let yourObject = {1:arr1, 2:arr2, 3:arr3}
let arrList = Object.values(yourObject);
```

an array assigned to a key in an object can be accessed like this

```
let yourObject = {'somekey':[1,2,3]};
arrList = yourObject.somekey;
console.log(arrList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But my array is as shown above in an edit(its inside an object). So I am getting an error. How to retrieve that value?

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, the accepted approach worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Basic thing to know before we continue :

- how many arrays you have ?
- can array be empty ?

if number of arrays is static i.e. 3 and they can't be empty then use [sabir.alam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2913723/sabbir-alam)'s
else please define your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter answer:

```js
const parentArr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[7,3,2,1]];
const answer = parentArr.map(e=>e[e.length-1]).reduce((x,y)=>x+y);
console.log(answer);
```